# C# LINQ join between multiple lists

Tags: c#, linq

I have a LINQ Joining statement in C# with which I'm trying to linq a list of structs with two lists of strings:

```
public struct ll
{
    public int index;
    public string one;
    public string two;
} 
public List <ll> list1;  //{"0,a, ", "1,," , "2,a,dog" , "3,,horse"}

public List <string> list2;    //{"a","b"}
public List <string> list3;    //{"cat","mouse","dog"}
```

The idea is that in list1 not all structs contains a value, so on index 0 only list1.one has a value being "a", list1.two is empty. On index 1 both list1.one and list1.two are empty. On index 2 both list1.one and list.two have values. On index 3 only list.two has a value.

With below I'm trying to join this three Lists

```
        var query = from x in list1
                    join y1 in list2 on x.one equals y1
                    join y2 in list3 on x.two equals y2
                    select x.index;
```

With this statement the join will only be done if list1.one matches an item in list2 and list1.two matches an item in list2.
However what I would like to see is that if only list1.one is filled, but list1.two is empty, the join will only match an item in list2 with list1.one, but will join with all items in list3, so taking the empty list1.two not in account.

EDIT:

Let me rephrase the question. My objective is that the program reads a sentence typed in by the user, stores infinitives, nouns, articles and adverbs in seperate lists and tries to find the best answer or reply for the user based on the join of all lists.

So list1 should look like

```
    public struct ll
    {
       int index;
       string infinitive;
       string noun;
       string article;
       string adverb;
       string answer;

    }
public List <ll> list1;
```

with below data:

[image]

When for example the user inputs the sentence 'what can you find' the join script should return two possible answers:

"I can find this information" and "What do you want me to find"

On the sentence "what can you find here"

it would only return:
"I can find this information"

But when the user askes: "what do you know about THIS hobbit" it would return nothing as the combination "know" and "this" is unknown, where as "what do you know about hobbit" would return with "This I know about"

Hope this is more clear know

Comment: Can you show us the resulting data you would like to see from the lists in your example?

Comment: Hi Bradley. For example: "a" (from list1) would match with {"a","cat","mouse","dog"}, and "" (from list1) would match with {"a","b","cat","mouse","dog"}. At the end x.index would return all indexes from list1 which could have been joined with both list2 and list3. Therefore it would return index 0, 1 and 2, because all items including empties could be matched. It would never return index 3 from list1 as it could not find "horse" in list3

Comment: So an empty string matches everything?

Comment: Yes, but as said if the item in list.two can not be found in list3 it would not return the x.index although list.one is empty

Comment: It would really help us if you could add a small chart of the expected output to your question.

Comment: Would the results be {0, a, a, cat} , {0, a, a, mouse}, {0, a, a, dog} or just {0, a, a, cat, mouse, dog}.  For the second case you'd need to group and put the matches into a collection.

Comment: See my edit. Apologises for not being more specific in the first place, but I was struggling to find the best way to ask the question...

Comment: Can you do it without LINQ? How does that code look like?

Comment: Knee-jerk is that you don't want to *join* all the lists.  Joining them implies you want order of list1*list2*list3*list4... records back.  I think you want order of list1*(list2+list3+list4+...) records.  This is something different, right?

Comment: It seems like `index` is redundant?  You can calculate it by which of `one` and `two` are null, and vice-versa, right?

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to tell exactly what you want, and especially how `index` is defined, but I'm guessing something like this.  You want `l1` to be some kind of input list of search terms per domain, and you want `l2`, `l3`, etc to be some kind of search domain.

`JOIN` is not the right way to go about this.  You're just wanting a linear search through the inputs, for domain matches.  You can nicely abstract this by, rather than having each domain be its own list, just make it a list-of-lists, and have those searched in order.  This is as follows:

```
var lists = new[]
                {
                    new[] { "a", null },
                    new string[] { null, null },
                    new[] { "a", "dog" },
                    new[] { null, "horse" }
                };
var domains = new[] { new[] { "a", "b" }, new[] { "cat", "mouse", "dog" } };

var matches = lists.Where(list => list.Where((s, i) => s == null || domains[i].Contains(s)).Count() == list.Length);

foreach (var list in matches)
{
    Console.WriteLine(string.Join(",", list));
}
```

Output:

```
"a",null
null,null
"a","dog"
```

Then certainly you can write a function that determines the corresponding `index` value for each list in the `matches`, if that's what you ultimately need.  I recommend you redefine your `index` to be a bitflag rather than the ad-hoc way you describe; then you can do:

```
static int GetIndex<T>(IEnumerable<T> list)
{
    return list.Select((s, i) => s == null ? 0 : 1 << i).Sum();
}
```

Or if you want to inline everything then it's simply

```
var indices = lists.Where(list => list.Where((s, i) => s == null || domains[i].Contains(s)).Count() == list.Length)
                   .Select(list => list.Select((s, i) => s == null ? 0 : 1 << i).Sum())
                   .Distinct();
```

Or if you define a nice helper indexed-All LINQ function, then maybe it makes things more clear:

```
public static bool All<T>(this IEnumerable<T> seq, Func<T, int, bool> pred)
{
    return seq.Select((x, i) => Tuple.Create(x, i)).All(t => pred(t.Item1, t.Item2));
}
```

...

```
IEnumerable<int> indices = lists
    .Where(list => list.All((s, i) => s == null || domains[i].Contains(s)))
    .Select(list => list.Select((s, i) => s == null ? 0 : 1 << i).Sum())
    .Distinct();
```